# If $|f(z)|\leq C\cdot |z|$ for some $C>0$, then $f(z)=az$ for some $a\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

My first guess was to define a function based off of the nearly entire quotient $f(z)/z$, and get it to be entire so that I could apply Liouville's Theorem. This didn't work, though. I'm trying to prove this without using arguments appealing to removable singularities and series expansion, so any help in this direction is appreciated! :)

Comment: Use the Cauchy estimates to show that $f''(z) = 0$ for all $z$ (or that $f'$ is bounded).

Comment: Hmm, I learned the estimation Theorem like this: if $f$ is analytic and bounded (by $C$) on a region $A$, and $\Gamma$ is a circle with radius $r$ centered at $z_0$ with $\Gamma$ and its interior lying in $A$, then $|f^{(k)}(z_0)|\leq k! \cdot r^{-k} \cdot M$ for all nonnegative $k$. I'm trying to apply the estimation theorem, but doesn't the bound have to be constant, and $C\cdot |z|$ is not?

Comment: You only need a bound on the contour. If you take a circle with centre $0$, the bound $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant C\lvert z\rvert$ easily translates to a bound for $\lvert f\rvert$ on the circle with radius $R$. (Yes, the bound depends on $R$, but so what?)

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you!